# How to force a win32 control to always validate the entire client area even when “Invalidate” was called with a partial rectangle

Tags: c++, winapi

I have my own version of EDIT control that is based on the original win32 control, I subclass edit’s windows procedure to do certain actions however the drawing is done by the original WM_PAINT.
So imagine something invalidates the rectangle of my control, but the rect that is passed is smaller than the client area therefore only part of my control is redrawn/validated. I’ve no control of that Invalidate call (comes from the OS). I need to have a way to somehow force repainting of the entire control even when partial validation was requested.
So far I’ve tried this:

1. Listen to WM_NCPAINT. The wParam is a handle to a region. I modified the region to include the entire client area.
2. Listen to WM_NCPAINT. Call InvalidateRect with entire client rectangle if wParam != 1 (that is only part of the window is to be validated).
   No 1 didn’t work at all. And No 2 is dodgy, calling InvalidateRect may or may not cause some sort of infinite loop, but it worked.

Is there anything else I can try? Thanks

Comment: This is an XY question, you cannot custom-paint an Edit control.  It commits a grave crime, it draws itself without using WM_PAINT.  Something it had to do back in the late 1980s to work acceptably on a 386sux.  You can't make this work reliably.

Comment: Subclass the `WM_PAINT` message and invalidate the entire client rect before forwarding to the original window procedure. When the original window procedure calls `BeginPaint` it will be told "Go paint the entire window." Note that what you have is a very dodgy design in the first place - can you explain your scenario more fully?

Comment: To Hans: I'm not trying to custom paint the control, in fact I want it to be natively drawn, all I need is to somehow simulate *full* redraw whenever a partial invalidation was requested.

Comment: To Raymond: that's what I've already tried in wm_ncpaint in my solution 2, but I'm afraid it might cause problems. The setup might only sounds dodgy because I left out some irrelevant details. I respond to WM_CTLCOLOREDIT message to provide a custom background, it works perfectly fine, until I switch off Aero. In non-aero mode a control is partially invalidated by the OS when another window is moved over that control screwing up the background.

Comment: If the background is patterned or otherwise non-uniform I seem to recall that `::SetWindowOrgEx()` can be used to 'trick' GDI into 'starting' the pattern from another location.

Comment: Hi user1793036, I'm already doing it. I'm using GetUpdateRect that suppose to give me a region that will be validated to calculate the offset for my brush. Unfortunately sometimes the function returns incorrect values (I'm still trying to figure out under which conditions) which results in offset being incorrectly calculated. I don't know if it's a Windows bug or something else.

Comment: Update to the above: I found out that the result of intersection of the rectangle received from GetUpdateRect and rectangle from GetClipBox can be used to calculate the offset for SetWindowOrgEx (GetUpdateRect wasn't enough). It's still not ideal, would have been great to always validate the entire region and not care about all the offset calculations.